# find コマンドの -exec オプションで {} と ; を ' ' (シングルクォート) で囲う意味について

Tags: macos, zsh

macでサブフォルダ内のファイルを親フォルダに集める操作を行いたいと考えています。次の記事を参考にしました。

[[Mac] サブフォルダ内のファイルを親フォルダに集める【フラット化のコマンド】](https://chiilabo.com/2020/09/mac-subfolder-flatten-automator-quick-action/)

下に示したコマンドを実行しようと考えています。

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' . ';'
```

前半の `find . -mindepth 2 type f` はカレントディレクトリ内で、2階層までのファイルを検索し、後半の `-exec mv -i '{}' . ';'` は検索したファイルをカレントディレクトリに移動している操作だと理解したのですが、後半の `{}` と `;` を `''` で囲う意味がよく理解できません。

質問は以下の３つです。

1. `{}` と `'{}'` は動作として異なるのか
2. `;` と `';'` は動作として異なるのか
3. `';'` と `\;` は同じ意味なのか

以上です。教えていただけると嬉しいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 本文はmacと書いているのにタグはlinuxですが、どちらなのでしょうか。使っているシェルはbashですか?

Comment: 理由はともかく、まずは実際に試して結果を自分で確認してみるのも一つの方法かと思います。

Comment: @int32_t ご指摘ありがとうございます。PCはmacで使っているシェルはzshです。タグの方も修正しました。不適切なタグの使い方をしてしまいすみませんでした。

Comment: @cubick  コメントありがとうございます。試行錯誤しました結果、`{}`の''は無くても問題なく実行できました。`;`は''を外すと` find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`のエラーが発生して実行できませんでした。`';'`を`\;`に書き換えた場合は問題なく実行できることがわかりました。アドバイスありがとうございました！

Comment: `{}` の quoting に関しては [Is there any reason to quote the placeholder in a find ... -exec command_to_run {} \; statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270420) が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: @cubick 本文の編集もありがとうございます。参考になります！

Comment: @metropolis `'{}'`とした場合は、ファイル名をただの文字としてシェルに認識されると理解しました。更に、シェルには多くの種類があり、各々で振る舞いが異なることも知りました。コメントありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{}` や `;` をクォート文字で囲むのは、それをそのまま`find`へのパラメーターとして渡すためです。
これらの文字はシェルにとって意味のある文字だからです。

たとえば最後の `;` を

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' . ;
```

のように書いてしまうと、この `;` はシェルにとっての「コマンドの区切り」なので、`find`へのパラメーターとしては`. -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i {} .`しか渡されないことになってしまいます。

`\;` も `;` をコマンドの区切りではなくただの文字としてエスケープするもので、意味は `';'` と同じです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。```' '```で囲うとシェルにとってただの文字として認識されるということですね。```;```をそのまま入力すると「コマンドの区切り」という、狙いとは異なる認識を、シェルにされることがわかりました。```{}```は```' '```で囲わない場合もエラーが出ずに実行できましたが、```' '```で囲ったほうが安全なのかと思いました。ご回答ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

[man find](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_findutils/man1/find.1.html) によると `{` や `}` や `;` は シェルにとって特別な文字なので `find` を起動しようとしたシェル (`bash` とか `zsh` とか `dash` とか) が先に処理してしまい `find` に渡されないから、適切にエスケープしないといけないよとあります。オイラの知る posix shell すべてで `;` は複文の意味になるので `;\` または `';'` と書く必要があります。

では `{}` のほうはどうかというと `{}` だけではシェルの特殊処理が起動されないので `find` の引数としては `'{}'` と書かなくてもいいことになっています。 `${PS1}` のように書くと環境変数の展開になるのですが。

`find` が見つけたファイル名にスペースが入っているとき `find . -exec mv {} .. \;` と書いたなら、ファイル名 `a qucik brown fox` に対して `mv a quick brown fox ..` のように展開されてしまうと、ファイル名 `a quick brown fox` がシェルによって `a` と `quick` と `brown` と `fox` に分割されてしまいそうに見えます。が、やはりオイラの知る限りの `find` は `{}` の結果（に空白類が含まれていても）１つの `argv` として渡してきます。なのでやはり `{}` を `'{}'` と書かなくてもよいようです。

が、まあ超絶古い商用 UNIX では `find` がバグっているかもしれないので安全のために `'{}'` と書きたがる人がいたような気がしなくもないっス。ウチの hpux11.11 の `/usr/bin/find` でも問題ないので今どき気にするほどのことは無さそうです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。`{}`はファイル名に空白がある場合でも分割されずに、1つの引数となるのですね。また、シェルの種類をほとんど知らなかったので、具体的なシェルを挙げながら説明していただけてとても助かりました！